# VBA - Loading master workbook using another workbook

Tags: vba

I got these 2 tables, 1 is a datatable, the 2nd is a instruction table.

everyday i will update the instruction table, and run the macro, which will update the datatable accordingly based on ID.

It is currently really simple. If datatable ID (Col A) matches instructiontable ID (Col J) then the corresponding data Col B-F will update according to instructiontable.

Datatable

Col A= ID

Col B-G = Different names

The instruction table is:

Col I is add (change to Y) or delete (change to N) Col K i

Col J is ID

COl K indicates which name (Header of Col B-G) to update.

```
Sub updatedatatable()

 On Error Resume Next

 Dim instructionlastrow, findtablecolumn, findtablerow As Long

 Dim findid As Integer

 instructionlastrow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To instructionlastrow

     findid = 0

     If Range("I" & i).Value = "Add" And Range("A:A").Find(Range("J" & i).Value).Row = 0 Then

         Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Range("J" & i).Value

         findtablecolumn = Rows(1).Find(Range("K" & i)).Column

         findtablerow = Range("A:A").Find(Range("J" & i)).Row

         Cells(findtablerow, findtablecolumn).Value = "Y"

     ElseIf Range("I" & i).Value = "Add" And Range("A:A").Find(Range("J" & i).Value).Row <> 0 Then

         findtablerow = Range("A:A").Find(Range("J" & i)).Row

         findtablecolumn = Rows(1).Find(Range("K" & i)).Column

         Cells(findtablerow, findtablecolumn).Value = "Y"

     ElseIf Range("I" & i).Value = "Remove" And Range("A:A").Find(Range("J" & i).Value).Row <> 0 Then

         findtablerow = Range("A:A").Find(Range("J" & i)).Row

         findtablecolumn = Rows(1).Find(Range("K" & i)).Column

         Cells(findtablerow, findtablecolumn).Value = "N"

     End If

 Next i
End Sub
```

i was wandering if anyone can teach me so that the Instruction table can be loaded from a different workbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure excactly what the relation of the two tables are supposed to be according to your description, but I understand as this; you currently have them in the same workbook (in the same worksheet?) but want to have them in different workbooks.

To access a workbook from another workbook in vba you can use the Workbooks.Open method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

I can also recommend some code examples from Ron de Bruin
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section3.htm

Since you haven't made any coding attempts to access separate workbooks I'm not 100% what you want to do, but please have a look at the links, make an attempt at a solution and get back if you get stuck again.

Comment: yeah you are correct, they are currently in the same worksheet. But I want to split them into different workbooks, it will make it easier to manage. I understand how to use the workbooks.open, but I am not sure how to make it all the checking/ updating based on the new opened workbook. If you can start me off on how to do that, then I can edit the rest of the codes accordingly. basically i want to update the datatable workbook according to the instruction workbook via the unique identifier and then update differently according to the instruction.